# Drupal sending mail atachment as pdf

Tags: email, drupal, pdf, send

Drupal 
here webform application  has uasing whiling
submiting the form mali has to send as pdf format with user filled details..

Answer (score 4):

I have Drupal 7 website and used Webfrom and Webform2PDF modules to mail PDF attachement containing fields that users entered in webform. The PDF can be pre-formatted with header, content and footer - just use %value[key] to pull in the fields from the webform.

Just reply if you need more help with this.

Answer (score 0):

que?

You want to send a pdf email or you want to download a pdf of the form data once a user has submitted it?

Comment: Yes i am sending the pdf the downloading the file but in case view its now displaying content